# Write data to cloud firestore with flutter async

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to write data in a firestore collection using async in my flutter app.

I do have this code, but it seems not to be working.

```dart
import 'package:location/location.dart';

Location _locationService = new Location();
  Future<void> setUserData() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> userData = <String, dynamic>{
      'email': this._emailController.text,
      'password': this._passwordController.text,
      'firstname': this._firstNameController.text,
      'familyname': this._familyNameController.text,
      'phonenumber': this._phoneNumberController.text,
      'neighbourhood': this._neighbourhoodController.text,
      'latitude': await _locationService.getLocation().latitude,
    };
    crudObj.addData(userData);
  }
```

crudObj.addData writes directly to my firestore collection.

What am i doing wrong  ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't imported cloud_firestore to begin with.

```
Future<void> setUserData() async {
Firestore.instance.collection(*name of collection*).document(*name of document*).setData(
    {'email': this._emailController.text,
 'password': this._passwordController.text, 
     'firstname': this._firstNameController.text,
    'familyname': this._familyNameController.text,
    'phonenumber': this._phoneNumberController.text,
    'neighbourhood': this._neighbourhoodController.text,
    'latitude': await _locationService.getLocation().latitude,});
```

}

I hope you setup your project to connect to cloud firestore